# How many simulation models are needed if the two lowest means, the lowest variance, and three out of the five variables are selected?

Tags: combinatorics

In a simulation study, a statistical model has $3$ components: mean, variance, and number of variables. Four different means, three different variances, and five different variables are considered. For each model, a statistician chooses one value from each component. How many simulation models are needed if the two lowest means, the lowest variance, and three out of the five variables are selected?

The final answer is $20$. But how?

I've done $C(3,5)$ for the variables and $P(4,2)$ and $P(3,1)$ for the means and variance respectively but when I add those all together I'm getting $28$. I honestly don't know where to start or if this line of thinking is even right.  Any tips to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no choice amongst the means, you just choose the least two.  Nor is there a choice amongst the variances, you just choose the least.

Answer (score 1):

So there are three out of five different variables selected, so ${ 5 \choose 3} = 10$. There is only one variance ever selected, the lowest one. There are two different means. So the total number of ways of combining these is:

${ 5 \choose 3}$ variables $* 1$ variance $* 2$ means

$=10 * 1 * 2 = 20$